# What qualifies as marital property?

Tags: united-states, divorce

Bob and Alice are getting divorced. They each have jobs, but Bob makes significantly more than Alice. They purchased a home together but each own their own cars prior to getting married. They also have separate bank accounts and a joint account for the bills they split. They also each have their own retirement accounts.

I know that specifics vary from each case and state. But typically what qualifies as "Martial Property"?

Comment: I think you will need to specify a state.

Comment: @mkennedy And/or a country.

Comment: It was tagged united-states.